# Error in bibliography, causing errors when adding new citations

Tags: bibtex, errors, texmaker

Hi everybody I'm new here so I'm unsure on how to post properly but I am currently writing a report using Texmaker and it has been going fine, with references all working as intended, however today when I started work when I added a new reference everything seemed to go wrong.

What I was doing before was adding a reference, then citing it and using the F11 key to run the bibtex file and everything worked fine. However now when I do this on the bibtex file it says

```
I couldn't open file name `References.aux'
```

I am unsure whether this was here before, but it may well have been. The real issue is when I try to add a new citation and press F11 then run, I get an error several hundred lines up saying there was a missing $ inserted and such when that part of the document was completely fine before, and is completely fine when I take the citation out from the later part of the text.

[image]

If I try to run the bibtex file, i get the error

```
Could not start the command. pdflatex-synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

But I don't think I ever needed to do this before.

I will also post the configuration here since on similar posts I have looked at which have been unable to help they seem to have also posted it, but once again I don't know if this is necessary as I am new. [image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated thanks!!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  Please include a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) that reproduces your error in your question.

Comment: After attempting many alterations I realised it was the one URL that was the problem in the citation, it is because it contained an underscore, but why is this a problem is there a simple fix to this?